# Get the latest download link programmatically

Tags: bash

I want to be able to download the latest version of a software automatically with my bash script. Unfortunately not ever website has the latest release link just like github.
In my case I need to download the latest **stable** version of Nginx

Currently I use this 
**http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.4.7.tar.gz**
and then I compile from source

The problem is that I will need to manually check for updates from time to time and update the link.

Is there any way that I can use to make my script grab the latest stable version of Nginx automatically

P.S installing via yum is not an option

Comment: I'd advise you to do whatever necessary to be notified of new stable versions and continue to download/compile manually. I know that doesn't answer your question but I feel it's sound advice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update**:
Solution that determines and downloads the latest ***stable* version** via `http://nginx.org/en/download.html` (`http://nginx.org/download/`, used in the original solution below, does not distinguish between stable and mainline versions) - works on both Linux and OSX:

```
# Determine the latest stable version's download URL, assumed to be 
# the first `/download/nginx-*.tar.gz`-like link following the header 
# "Stable version".
latestVer=$(curl -s 'http://nginx.org/en/download.html' | 
   sed 's/</\'$'\n''</g' | sed -n '/>Stable version$/,$ p' | 
   egrep -m1 -o '/download/nginx-.+\.tar\.gz')

# Download.
curl "http://nginx.org${latestVer}" > nginx-latest.tar.gz
```

Note: This relies on specifics of the HTML structure of page `http://nginx.org/en/download.html`, which is not the most robust solution.

---

**Original solution** that determines the latest version via `http://nginx.org/download/`, where no distinction is made between stable and mainline versions:

On **Linux**, try:

```
 # Determine latest version:
 latestVer=$(curl 'http://nginx.org/download/' | 
   grep -oP 'href="nginx-\K[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | 
   sort -t. -rn -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 | head -1)

 # Download latest version:
 curl "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${latestVer}.tar.gz" > nginx-latest.tar.gz
```

This does NOT rely on a specific listing order at `http://nginx.org/download/`; instead, version numbers are extracted and sorted appropriately.

---

On **OSX** - where `grep` doesn't support `-P` and `\K` for dropping the left part of a match is not available, try:

```
# Determine latest version:
latestVer=$(curl 'http://nginx.org/download/' | 
 egrep -o 'href="nginx-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | sed 's/^href="nginx-//' |
 sort -t. -rn -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 | head -1)

# Download latest version:
curl "http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${latestVer}.tar.gz" > nginx-latest.tar.gz
```

Comment: Updated script also works on Windows 10 with Bash 

Answer (score 2):

This will determine the latest *stable* version:

```
$ lynx -dump http://nginx.org/en/download.html \
    | awk '/Stable/{t=1}t&&/nginx-/{$0=$2;sub(/.+\]/,"");print;exit}'
nginx-1.4.7
```

Use this result to assemble a proper download URL and use `wget`/`curl` to download.

This will determine the download URL of the *most recent* release:

```
$ lynx -dump http://nginx.org/download/ | awk '/nginx-.*\.zip$/{url=$2}END{print url}'
http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.5.9.zip
```

This relies on their webserver sorting the directory listing by date (which it currently does).

Comment: Looks gr8 as well another it require lynx but are you sure that it would grap the latest stable version not mainline

Comment: @user2650277 You are right, I overlooked that detail in your question. I have updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Wish i could accept both your answer and that of @mklement0.Since he provided a solution that work on both linux and osx without use of third party tools , he deserve to be accepted answer:) but your is awesome as well

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know OSX shipped with `curl`. No worries :-)

Comment: +1 for concision; prerequisite is availability of `lynx`, which is not installed by default on most platforms.

Answer (score 0):

**If use of third-party tools is acceptable**, here's another option using the **multi-platform web-scraping CLI [xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html#downloads)**:

```
curl "http://nginx.org$( \
   xidel 'http://nginx.org/en/download.html' \
     -e '(//a[matches(@href, "/download/nginx-.+\.tar\.gz$")])[2]/@href' \
   )" -O
```

The command uses an XPath expression to extract the URL of interest; here the assumption is that the *2nd*  `/download/nginx-*.tar.gz` link on the page is the *stable* version (the first one representing the mainline version).

This is not the most robust approach, but that's an inherent problem with scraping web pages that weren't designed for programmatic consumption.

Answer (score 0):

found it at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/23701

```
wget http://lftp.yar.ru/ftp/$(wget -O- http://lftp.yar.ru/ftp/ | egrep -o 'lftp-[0-9\.]+.tar.gz' | sort -V  | tail -1)
```

might be a simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

Getting latest nginx and naxsi versions, doesnt require sorting but requires [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```
latestNginx=$(curl -s http://hg.nginx.org/nginx/tags |
  grep "^ *release-" | head -1 | cut -c 9-)
latestNaxsi=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/nbs-system/naxsi/releases |
  jq -r .[].tag_name | grep -v rc | head -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another short solution for getting and downloading the latest stable version of nginx:

**This was tested in a Linux environment and may not work on MacOS**

> Replace the word **Stable** with **Mainline** to get the latest mainline version

```bash
curl "http://nginx.org$(curl -s http://nginx.org/en/download.html | grep -oP 'Stable version.*?\K(/download/.*?tar.gz)')" --output nginx-stable.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to use this same approach to script Downloading latest current/stable Node version too without any special requirements.

Download Latest LTS Node Version:

```
latestLTSNode=$(curl -s https://nodejs.org/en/download/ | grep -E "Latest LTS Version: <strong>[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+"|grep -oE "[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+"| head -n1) ; nodejs_url="https://nodejs.org/dist/v${latestLTSNode}/node-v${latestLTSNode}-linux-x64.tar.xz"; wget ${nodejs_url} ; filename=$(basename $nodejs_url); filefolder=$(echo $filename | sed 's|.tar.xz||g') ;
```

Download Latest Current node Version:

```
latestCurrentNode=$(curl -s https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/ | grep -E "Latest Current Version: <strong>[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+"|grep -oE "[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+"| head -n1) ; nodejs_url="https://nodejs.org/dist/v${latestCurrentNode}/node-v${latestCurrentNode}-linux-x64.tar.xz"; wget ${nodejs_url} ; filename=$(basename $nodejs_url); filefolder=$(echo $filename | sed 's|.tar.xz||g') ;
```